# How to use Django Models in template sent through AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax, serialization

I am trying to undertake the following steps:

1. submit a form with AJAX
2. catch the form fields in my `views.py`
3. use the form fields to create a filter and obtain a queryset: `queryset = Movielensrecommendation.objects.all().filter(**q)`
4. serialize my queryset: `serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('python', queryset)`
5. put serialized object in a dictionary `response_data['table'] = serialized_obj`
6. return a JSON response `return JsonResponse(response_data)`
7. catch the JSON response in my AJAX function `success: function (json) {`
8. return the models to my template

Steps 1-3 I've got down. Steps 4-7 are solely because, from what I understand, that this is the way to go. Step 8 is the Horcrux.

my `Model objects` are serialized, but I do not understand:

- How to send the models to the template from my JS where I catch them (step 7)
- How to iterate through these `Model objects` in my template (or in JS?)

**NOTE:**
In Django I can return a render with the models in the context using

```
context = {'table': queryset} 
return render(request, 'journal/index.html', context}
```

This way in my template I can access both the original model fields AND the joined models using Foreignkeys. It is important that I am also able to do so after the JSON response:

```
{% for item in table %}
    {{ item.field1 }}
    {{ item.OTHERMODEL.field1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here's my setup.

```
views.py

def show_movielens(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            q = {}
            # retrieve data from AJAX POST
            gender = request.POST.get('post_gender')
            age = request.POST.get('post_age')
            occupation = request.POST.get('post_occupation')

            if age != 'all':
                q.update({'user__age_range': age})
            if gender != 'all':
                q.update({'user__gender': gender})
            if occupation != 'all':
                q.update({'user__occupation': occupation})

            queryset = Movielensrecommendation.objects.all().filter(**q)
            serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('python', queryset)

            response_data = {}
            response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
            response_data['table'] = serialized_obj

            return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

```
main.js


$('#submit_form').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); //so that we stop normal form submit.
   post_form();

});

function post_form() {

   $.ajax({
       url: 'show_movielens/',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       data : { post_gender : $('#post-gender').val(),
           post_age : $('#post-age').val(),
           post_occupation : $('#post-occupation').val(),
       }, // data sent with the post request
       success: function (json) {
           console.log("succes?");

           // WHAT DO I DO HERE ???
           // HOW DO I unpack the JSON.table models in my template??

       },
       error: function(error){
           console.log(error);
       },
   });
}
```

```
index.html template

       <div class="row" id="responding_json">

       <!-- WHAT COMES HERE ???? -->


        </div>

        <div class="row" id="form-inputs">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form action="show_movielens/" method="POST" id="form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                        {{  form.gender }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                        {{  form.age }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                        {{  form.occupation }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" id="submit_form">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The form works, the url works, data gets sent to the view and the queryset is build nicely. I serialize it using `python`, which also seems to work. I just don't understand how to 'unpack' these models and iterate over them while maintaining the possibility to use the INNER JOINS on them (as explained in the note).

Comment: As far as I can tell, you'll want to *either* a) return JSON/pure data to the client-side, to use it directly *or* b) send back a rendered template, i.e. HTML. Template rendering based on data is done on the server, so I don't see why you would do steps 4-7 if the desired behavior involves a server-side HTML template.

Comment: I don't understand. I am updating a part of my index.html using an AJAX form. The only way (so far that I do understand) that this is possible is to catch a JSON response in my ajax. The question is how to show this JSON response in my template and make use of Django's model functionality?

Comment: But the response from Ajax doesn't have to be JSON. It can be a rendered template fragment, which you can insert directly into the existing page.

Comment: Okay.. How would I do that? I can directly send my Django models in a HttpResponse and catch that in Ajax? Is there a resource that I can read for this?

Comment: No, that's not what I said at all. You can just render a template in your show_movielens view and return it as normal.

Comment: I really do not understand. I looked at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627978/return-django-models-for-template-rendering-after-an-ajax-request, but still don't get it.

Comment: What's not to get? Imagine you're not using Ajax. You would render a template in your view that uses the models. So just do that.

Comment: Did I mention that the form and the actual output are on the same page? How can I render a template in my view that is already rendered? I am using AJAX to prevent reloading the template, that's the whole idea of AJAX right?

Comment: As far as I can tell you need to 1. create a template that isn't a complete document but just, say, a `<table>`. 2. make an ajax request, and have django render the `<table>` based on the template and data, then send it back 3. the ajax success handler receives the table HTML and inserts it into the page

Comment: Just to be really clear: clicking a link/sending a POST form and AJAX use the exact same mechanism, an http request. The server doesn't know or care which one it is. The difference to the browser is that in the first case, the browser will navigate to the reply, i.e. render the reply in its main window, while in the AJAX case it'll simply pass it to success callback. In the case of a Django website, the first variety should return a full HTML document, while the AJAX one can pass back whatever (or nothing, if it's just about telling the server about something).

Comment: Yes, thank you! I've got it working now